# why am i having error after Neo4j 1.1.10 installation

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

Downloaded the Neo4j Desktop app from the download link in Neo4j website i.e https://neo4j.com/download/ .
After installation i am getting this error

```
Updater error: HttpError: 403 Forbidden "<?xml version=\"1.0\"                         
encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access 
Denied</Message><RequestId>F18F752D5FDCDFCE</RequestId> 
<HostId>gvxjrw0jzdGpX79EfRqlsCuKCtpb+V1xQHFw6+D767956fKibxsGuXrGdOuaucJ9q
61zXCi7dlo=</HostId></Error>" Headers: { "connection": [ "keep-alive" ], 
"content-type": [ "application/xml" ], "date": [ "Wed, 31 Oct 2018 09:51:14 
GMT" ], "server": [ "AmazonS3" ], "transfer-encoding": [ "chunked" ], "via": 
[ "1.1 9b0b072d7d081c8dd193aa49a39626f2.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)" ], "x- 
amz-cf-id": [ "Rh6SG57jZRXEB5ZlGPPZi51RPPMpEx_GVfMCbN_J5iEjrADgaIPVTg==" ], 
"x-cache": [ "Error from cloudfront" ] }
```

Comment: What action causes this error?

Comment: Neo4j 1.1.10? Are you sure about that???

Comment: yes @manonthemat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm with Neo4j.

There was an issue with the recent Desktop release, some of the actions taken to limit the issue pulled some files that are involved with checking for version updates and were responsible for that message.

A new version of Desktop has already been released, files fixed up for version updates, and this message should no longer be coming up.